# Spring Persist Failure, JSON with FK, FK null

Tags: java, json, spring, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 entities, PurchaseRequest (PR) and PurchaseRequestLineItem (PRLI). They follow a typical relationship pattern in that PR has many PRLIs.  I've annotated PR w/ a @OneToMany on PRLI, and PRLI w/ a @ManyToOne back to PR.  I can insert a PR just fine, but if I try to insert a PRLI on its own, with a reference to the PR, I keep getting the error "Column 'PurchaseRequestID' cannot be null".  Below is my code.  I've found that if I remove the @JsonIgnore annotation in the PRLI purchaseRequest variable the insert will work, but then the getAll fails due to infinite recursion.  How do I solve for this?

JSON (yes, these IDs are valid):

```
{
    "PurchaseRequest": {
        "Id":658
    },
    "ProductID": 2,
    "Quantity": 1
}
```

PurchaseRequest.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="purchaserequest")
public class PurchaseRequest implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="UserID") 
    private User user;
    ....
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="purchaserequestid")
    private List<PurchaseRequestLineItem> lineItems;
```

PurchaseRequestLineItem.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="purchaserequestlineitem")
public class PurchaseRequestLineItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PurchaseRequestID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest;
    private int productID;
    private int quantity;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two annotations to solve the infinite recursion problem without using @JsonIgnore : 
--@JsonManagedReference

### --@JsonBackReference

@JsonManagedReference 
  private List lineItems;

@JsonBackReference
  private PurchaseRequest purchaseRequest;

Comment: Thanks.  I've been testing this and running into other issues.  Need to resolve those before continuing.

Comment: An update...  this ultimately worked.. thank you!  I shelved this work at the time because more pressing items came up but on a re-visit I got this working.